# What is the best tutorial for learning MPI for C++?

Tags: c++, mpi

I plan to use MPI for my C++ code. I have installed MPICH2 on my computers. But I do not know much about MPI and hope to find some materials to read. I hope you experts can recommend some good materails to me. Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: MPI:  Message Passing Interface, a computer communications protocol for parallel computation.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm assuming you already know how to program C++ pretty well and have a basic understanding of parallel programming (or at least know how you want to parallelize your code).

I would check out the book [Using MPI](http://books.google.com/books?id=xpBZ0RyRb-oC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Using+MPI&source=bl&ots=u9fwk2OH6U&sig=IjtfxQm7KGa0-FSTvChGJL4Ax6M&hl=en&ei=z-B6S9yzKI2qswPspt3LCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CAkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=&f=false) first.  Using MPI 2 is the follow on book that discusses using the new bits in MPi-2.  Both books were written by the guys who wrote the MPI library and headed up the standardization effort.  One nice thing about Using MPI is that it's available online so you can check it out w/o spending money :-)

Comment: +1 from me. One small issue, which might or might not be a problem: switches between Fortran, C, and C++ sample code.

Comment: I agree it could be a bit annoying, but I didn't find it to be a significant detriment to understanding when I was using the book.

Answer (score 8):

[Parallel Programming with MPI](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558603395) by Peter S. Pacheco is a good intro book. Note, the book uses C, but it should be an easy transition to using the C++ MPI bindings.

Comment: +1  This book is a great introduction to MPI programming.

Comment: I think the book is a good way to learn to program with MPI.  If you find my answer, you will discover that I do not favor using C++ for any new MPI development.  Since you fail to mention a similar caution, no upvote.  You did still get a supportive comment.  ;)

Comment: Pacheco's book was written many years ago.  Is it still useful?

Comment: The content is still relevant in my opinion.

Answer (score 7):

LLNL has [a pretty good one](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi/).

Answer (score 6):

I would advise against using the MPI C++ bindings for any new development.  The program itself can be in C++, but invest the extra effort to use the C interface to the MPI library.

The MPI Forum is deprecating the C++ bindings.  So, future implementations of MPI will probably drop support for C++.  In general, most implementations skimp on features when it comes to C++.  The basics will work, but things like dynamic processes (i.e. spawn), the PMPI interfaces, and so on are less well supported.

The C and Fortran bindings are reasonably well supported by all the major implementations, and will continue to be supported into the foreseeable future.

Comment: For those who intent to stick with C++ which are the alternatives to MPI? To my knowledge its the only way to split things across different machines. There is OpenMP and CUDA but that's another business - I'll say.

Answer (score 6):

As @semiuseless pointed out, the MPI forum is deprecating the C++ bindings. One of the reasons for that is that the [boost MPI interface](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/mpi.html) does a much better job.

Answer (score 2):

some get started manual may be found on [LAM/MPI site](http://www.lam-mpi.org/tutorials/)

Answer (score 2):

Mpich2 comes with a number of examples in C++/C.  probably the most famous is cpi, which computes pi in parallel.  Read through the program together with manuals/books other people suggested.  This way you will see actual working code right away and can make your own modifications to play with things.